# C++: what is the best way to handle this multi-inheritance?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

A page is basically a fixed size array of a type - but it provides other functionality which isn't important for this question. Specifically, each page has a `recordOffset` which implies that the record IDs for the page are sequential and begin at this index (a page can be viewed as a discreet arbitrary segment of a larger array)

```
class AbstractPage
{
    protected:
        unsigned int recordOffset;

    public:
        AbstractPage(unsigned int recordOffset);
        virtual ~AbstractPage();

        // a mixture of pure and non-pure virtual functions
        virtual string toString() const;
        virtual unsigned int getCount() const = 0;
        virtual PageType pageType() const = 0;
};

class IntegerPage : public AbstractPage
{
    public:
        vector<int> data;

        IntegerPage(const vector<int>& data);
        virtual ~IntegerPage();

        // our concrete implementation
        virtual unsigned int getCount() const;
        virtual PageType pageType() const;
};

class FloatPage : public AbstractPage
{
    public:
        vector<float> data;

        FloatPage(const vector<float>& data);
        virtual ~FloatPage();

        // our concrete implementation
        virtual unsigned int getCount() const;
        virtual PageType pageType() const;
};
```

I don't want to use templates for this because these pages get used liked this;

```
LinkedList<AbstractPage> pages;
```

I will use the interface methods provided by `AbstractPage` to interact with the page in most cases. When I need to read/write the data directly I will know the type separately and use:

```
dynamic_cast<FloatPage>(abstractPage).data[0] = 12.34;
```

So far so good, but here is the dilemma; I need to extend every type to create an indexed version of the page:

```
class AbstractIndexedPage
{
    public:
        // this is instead of the recordOffset of AbstractPage
        vector<unsigned int> recordIds;
};

class IndexedIntegerPage : public AbstractIndexedPage, public IntegerPage
{
};
```

Now I want to be able to do this:

```
AbstractIndexedPage sort(const AbstractPage& page)
{
    // Sorting will swap around the data and therefore we need to keep track of the
    // record IDs in an Indexed page.
    // If the incoming concrete type is IntegerPage, the output will be
    // IndexedIntegerPage
}
```

The problem is the returned object will not have the interface to `AbstractPage`:

```
AbstractIndexedPage sortedPage = sort(originalPage);
sortedPage.getCount(); // can't do this!
dynamic_cast<AbstractPage>(sortedPage).getCount() // can do this, but pretty messy
```

From what I've read multiple inheritance in all but select cases means your code is basically designed badly. In this case there is multiple inheritance from two non-interfaces, both of the classes will have a constructor (and virtual destructor) but will only ever directly deal with the instance variables they provide.

My options are:

1. `AbstractIndexedPage` extends `AbstractPage` and use `virtual` inheritance since there will now be two `AbstractPage`. But that will give me the complete interface. But isn't this a naughty hack?
2. Just duplicate `data` or `recordIds` instance variables in `IndexedIntegerPage` and `IntegerPage` to give the same functionality without the need for inheritance.
3. Design the architecture differently?

Thanks

Comment: Did you think in delegation? Where `AbstractIndexedPage` has a member of type `AbstractPage` and any instance of `ConcreteIndexedPage` is inicialized with an instance of `ConcretePage`.

Comment: Can you explain further? If there is an instance of `AbstractPage` inside of `AbstractInstancePage` then `AbstractInstancePage` still need to expose (duplicate) all the methods from `AbstractPage` on top of `AbstractInstancePage`?

Comment: No, when you need some operations on `AbstractClass`, you ask `AbstractIndexedPage` to give you a reference to an `AbstractClass` object and do the work as planned, for example, getting the `count()`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, that would be a perfectly legitimate solution. However now I'm more curious if both interfaces could be safely provided by one instance.

Comment: I you have used `IndexedIntegerPage` instead of `AbstractIndexedPage` you could have called `sortedPage.getCount()` without problem. The problem is the `AbstractIndexedPage` knows about nothing about `AbstractPage`

Comment: Exactly. There in lies the dilemma.

Comment: So, the problem is not with multi inheritance, but with your architecture

Comment: True, it's not necessarily a multi-inheritance problem. More a question whether it can be done safely with multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use delegation to do this work. For example, at `AbstractIndexedPage`:

```
class AbstractIndexedPage
{
    public:
        // this is instead of the recordOffset of AbstractPage
        vector<unsigned int> recordIds;
        AbstractClass* getPage() { return page;};
    private:
        AbstractClass *page;
};
```

and do something like that:

```
AbstractIndexedPage sortedPage = sort(originalPage);
sortedPage.getPage()->getCount(); // can't do this!
```

of course, verifying all possible errors or exeptions.

P.S. Someone will tell you to use smart pointer and I will agree with them, but, for simplicity, I just use plain pointer either

Comment: So far this is my favourite solution. I still want to know if there a way to put them together. Perhaps separate the pure interface of `AbstractPage` and apply it back to `AbstractPage` and `AbstractIndexedPage` then create forwarder methods from `AbstractIndexedPage` to the respective methods of the `AbstractPage` contained instance variable? Might work, but also creates more work that what's required...

Answer (score 1):

I was going to post this in comments, but the code will look terrible. You might consider abstracting at a lower level: create an `AnyType`, and just one Page Type based on it:

```
union AnyType {
    float f;
    int i;
};

class AnyPage : public AbstractPage
{
public:
    enum PageDataType {FloatPage, IntPage};

    vector<AnyType> data;

    AnyPage(const vector<int>& data); //creates an 'IntPage'
    AnyPage(const vector<float>& data); //creates a 'FloatPage'
    virtual ~AnyPage();

    // our concrete implementation
    virtual unsigned int getCount() const;
    virtual PageType pageType() const;

private:
    PageDataType myType;
};
```

Then you can create your linked lists of `AnyPage`, and as you said, you already know which kind of page you are dealing with when you want to access the data:

```
anyPage.data[0].f = 12.34;
```

Then, for the indexed variety, it is no longer multiple inheritance:

```
class AnyIndexedPage : public AnyPage
{
public:
    // this is instead of the recordOffset of AnyPage
    vector<unsigned int> recordIds;
};
```

Comment: That's how it was originally written in C, using `void *data` and using `switch(type)` around everywhere. I don't like that for C++ because I want pages that contain special types (like strings or more complex data) to have their logic in a self contained class - and not pollute one massive class.

Comment: Oh no, I think my roots are showing. You are quite right, as the number of types of pages increases, this solution becomes worse.

Comment: @ElliotChance, now that I think about it, where is all of the `switch`ing needed? Probably when dealing with `data`. In that case, you could create an AbstractData class, with concrete implementations for the different types. In the constructor for AnyPage, you pick the appropriate concrete Data class (for example, in the AnyPage constructor that accepts vector<int>, you create `IntData`) -- and voila, no switching needed. So, I guess this amounts to just adding one more layer of abstraction.